# Backbone multi events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand following code:

```
muConfigView.on("mu:field:changed", function() {
  updateButtonState();
}, this);
```

or

```
this.trigger('validate:fields');
```

I have seen examples with events like change etc which I understand.

Could some one explain me what the purpose of `"mu:field:changed"` & `'validate:fields'` is?

Comment: I've never worked with backbone.js, but they're probably just identifiers for the events being thrown (as `click` or `mousedown` in the DOM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone has it's own [events built in](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog), but you can also make up your own, which you can trigger and listen for.

The convention is to "namespace" events using colons (`:`) so that you can better organise your code as it can soon get out of hand once you start using a lot of events.

In your first example, when the `mu:field:changed` is triggered, the anonymous function will be called.

In your second example, the `validate:fields` event is being fired and will be handled by a listener somewhere else.

Comment: Got it, so these are custom events in backbone. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. You'd typically use `change` for events that monitor when a model attribute changes like `firstname:change`, so I assume `mu:field:changed` is custom.